# ASP.NET Non-Static Class Within a Static Class Thread-Safety

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety, static

Stack Overflow.  Let's say I want to initialize a non-static class of variables, two of which are a UserID (int) and MyDictionary (Dictionary).  This non-static class is declared within a static class (and initialized in one of the static class's members).
If the script runs long and another user accesses the same page, there's a chance the new user will alter the contents of the other user's MyDictionary.  But I don't see how this is possible since MyDictionary is in a non-static class.  Does anyone understand this?  Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get it from that one user would be able to modify server-side stuff that is used by someone else? Servers make seperate threads and memory for every user if i'm not mistaken. And also I'd recommend that you put all your classes in seperate files except if you have a private class used only in 1 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming the code looks a little like this right?

```
public class MyNonStaticClass
{
    public int UserID;

    public Dictionary<int, string> MyDictionary 
        = new Dictionary<int, string>;
}

public static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static MyNonStaticClass aStaticInstanceOfTheNonStaticClass 
        = new MyNonStaticClass();

    public static void AddToDictionary(int key, string value)
    {
        aStaticInstanceOfTheNonStaticClass.add(key, value);
    }
}
```

By declaring the object inside the static class as a static variable you are basically saying "In my application I want one of these; and only one of these"; so even though the class is not static; you are still creating a static instance of it.

Comment: Man, I figured this out about an hour, and your answer confirms it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Static-ness (or lack thereof) does **not** affect thread safety.  Static simply means that a class member (a property, field, method, or constructor) is associated with the *type* and not with *a particular instance* of a class.

I can write static code that is not thread safe (like the code you describe in your question) and I can write instance code that is thread safe, and vice versa.  Here is some **non-threadsafe (bad)** code, more or less along the lines of what I think you are doing:

```
public static class MyFoo {

    // Just because this is a static property doesn't
    // mean the contained dictionary is thread safe!
    public static Dictionary<String, String> MyDictionary { get; set; }

    public static MyFoo() {
        MyDictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    }
}
```

If you need to store user-specific information in ASP.NET, use the Session object or (for longer-lived data) a database.  Don't ever rely on a static variable- what if two users are on the site at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Because the containing class and the accessing member is static, it uses singular memory space. You must assume the static class's references (locals, fields or properties in this case) are also static (even if they're an instantiation of a non-static class).

What's the reason the class is static in the first place? If you're using shared logic, why not pass the Dictionary by reference to the static method?